# Using Cygwin on windows 8 - missing cygpng15-15.dll

Tags: windows, cygwin

Unfortunately, I really have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to using cygwin.  All I need it for is to run a program known as xfig.  I have installed cygwin using the instructions provided [here](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup-cygwin-x-installing.html).  I believe I have done all the steps correctly.  However, when I try and start xfig using the command $ xfig &, I am given this error`$ /usr/bin/xfig.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygpng15-15.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
I'm not sure what to do about this.  Am I missing some sort of library that I need to use cygwin?  I am running on Windows 8.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this command:

```
cygcheck --package-query cygpng15-15.dll
```

Which will return a lot of crap:

```
Found 5 matches for cygpng15-15.dll
cygwin32-libpng-1.5.12-1 - cygwin32-libpng: PNG library for Cygwin 32bit toolchain (installed binaries and support files)
libpng15-debuginfo-1.5.21-2 - libpng15-debuginfo: Debug info for libpng15 (installed binaries and support files)
libpng15-debuginfo-1.5.22-1 - libpng15-debuginfo: Debug info for libpng15 (installed binaries and support files)
libpng15-1.5.21-2 - libpng15: PNG library (installed binaries and support files)
libpng15-1.5.22-1 - libpng15: PNG library (installed binaries and support files)
```

Removing first line and leaving only package names gives us this:

```
cygwin32-libpng
libpng15-debuginfo
libpng15-debuginfo
libpng15
libpng15
```

Assuming you are on 64-bit Windows with 64-bit Cygwin, you can remove any
cygwin32 packages. Also we can ignore debuginfo packages as they only contain
files for /usr/lib/debug. Removing those and duplicates we are left with:

```
libpng15
```

Or you can just use my script:

```
$ apt-cyg searchall cygpng15-15.dll
libpng15
```

Comment: I have added this package and it seems to have resolved this specific problem.  I'm still running into problems, but those are different questions.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: by the way, I have now figured everything out and have just gotten xfig to run.  Thanks again.